# Inserting back Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin action doesn't show the Resolve option in Check-in

Tags: tfs

When I try to do a check-in in Visual Studio 2013 (TFS 2013 connected) and relate to a Bug type Work Item, the Resolve action doesn't appear as a option (only Associate option appears). I already checked the bug Work item workflow from Tools/Process Editor/Work Item Types/Open WIT from Server (in Visual Studio) and the states match with the selected bug workitem that i try to relate. The action Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin is in the transition between this states. Still, the Resolve action doesn't appear. When I try to relate to a Task type Work Item both options in check-in appear: Resolve and Associate. To do a test, I edit the Task Work Item type workflow and remove the Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin action in the transition related to the states that I try to test. The result was expected: the Resolve option in the check-in is not showing anymore, only associate. The problem is when I inserted back the Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin action the Resolve option does not appear back as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0"       xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/type  def">
   <WORKITEMTYPE name="Task">
        <DESCRIPTION>Tracks work that needs to be done.</DESCRIPTION>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD name="Iteration Path" refname="System.IterationPath" type="TreePath" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Iteration ID" refname="System.IterationId" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="External Link Count" refname="System.ExternalLinkCount" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="Team Project" refname="System.TeamProject" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Hyperlink Count" refname="System.HyperLinkCount" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="Attached File Count" refname="System.AttachedFileCount" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="Node Name" refname="System.NodeName" type="String" />
      <FIELD name="Area Path" refname="System.AreaPath" type="TreePath" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Revised Date" refname="System.RevisedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="detail" />
      <FIELD name="Changed Date" refname="System.ChangedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="ID" refname="System.Id" type="Integer" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Area ID" refname="System.AreaId" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="Authorized As" refname="System.AuthorizedAs" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" />
      <FIELD name="Title" refname="System.Title" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <REQUIRED />
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="State" refname="System.State" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Authorized Date" refname="System.AuthorizedDate" type="DateTime" />
      <FIELD name="Watermark" refname="System.Watermark" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="Rev" refname="System.Rev" type="Integer" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Changed By" refname="System.ChangedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Reason" refname="System.Reason" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
        <VALIDUSER />
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Work Item Type" refname="System.WorkItemType" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Created Date" refname="System.CreatedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Created By" refname="System.CreatedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
      <FIELD name="Description" refname="System.Description" type="HTML" />
      <FIELD name="History" refname="System.History" type="History" />
      <FIELD name="Related Link Count" refname="System.RelatedLinkCount" type="Integer" />
      <FIELD name="Tags" refname="System.Tags" type="PlainText" />
      <FIELD name="Remaining Work" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
        <HELPTEXT>Remaining hours to complete task</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Backlog Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority" type="Double" reportable="detail" />
      <FIELD name="Activity" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
          <LISTITEM value="Development" />
          <LISTITEM value="Testing" />
          <LISTITEM value="Requirements" />
          <LISTITEM value="Design" />
          <LISTITEM value="Deployment" />
          <LISTITEM value="Documentation" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="Deployment" />
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Integration Build" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">
          <LISTITEM value="&lt;None&gt;" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
          <GLOBALLIST name="Builds - iLang" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Blocked" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
          <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Description HTML" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml" type="HTML" />
      <FIELD name="Estimated" refname="iLang.Task.Estimated" type="Integer">
        <HELPTEXT>Estimated hours to complete task</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Estimate" refname="iLang.Task.Estimate" type="Double">
        <REQUIRED />
      </FIELD>
    </FIELDS>
    <WORKFLOW>
      <STATES>
        <STATE value="Done">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="Removed">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
        <STATE value="To Do" />
        <STATE value="In Progress" />
      </STATES>
      <TRANSITIONS>
        <TRANSITION from="To Do" to="In Progress">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work started" />
          </REASONS>
          <ACTIONS>
            <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.CheckIn" />
            <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork" />
          </ACTIONS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <ACTIONS>
            <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" />
          </ACTIONS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="" to="To Do">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="New task" />
          </REASONS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="To Do" to="Removed">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Removed from the backlog" />
          </REASONS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="Removed">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Removed from the backlog" />
          </REASONS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Done" to="In Progress">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Additional work found" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork">
              <REQUIRED />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="To Do">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work stopped" />
          </REASONS>
          <ACTIONS>
            <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork" />
          </ACTIONS>
        </TRANSITION>
      </TRANSITIONS>
    </WORKFLOW>
    <FORM>
      <Layout>
        <Group>
          <Column PercentWidth="100">
            <Control FieldName="System.Title" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;Title:" LabelPosition="Left" />
            <Control FieldName="System.IterationPath" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="Ite&amp;ration:" LabelPosition="Left" />
          </Column>
        </Group>
        <Group Label="">
          <Column PercentWidth="50">
            <Group Label="Status">
              <Column PercentWidth="100">
                <Control FieldName="System.AssignedTo" Type="FieldControl" Label="Assi&amp;gned To:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="System.State" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;State:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="System.Reason" Type="FieldControl" Label="Reason:" LabelPosition="Left" ReadOnly="True" />
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked" Type="FieldControl" Label="Blocked:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Column>
          <Column PercentWidth="50">
            <Group Label="Details">
              <Column PercentWidth="100">
                <Control FieldName="iLang.Task.Estimate" Type="FieldControl" Label="Estimate:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" Type="FieldControl" Label="Remaining Work:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" Type="FieldControl" Label="Activity:" LabelPosition="Left" />
                <Control FieldName="System.AreaPath" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="Area:" LabelPosition="Left" />
              </Column>
            </Group>
          </Column>
        </Group>
        <Group>
          <Column PercentWidth="50">
            <TabGroup>
              <Tab Label="Description">
                <Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
              </Tab>
            </TabGroup>
          </Column>
          <Column PercentWidth="50">
            <TabGroup>
              <Tab Label="History">
                <Control FieldName="System.History" Type="WorkItemLogControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill" />
              </Tab>
              <Tab Label="Links">
                <Control Type="LinksControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" Name="GeneralLinks">
                  <LinksControlOptions>
                    <LinkColumns>
                      <LinkColumn RefName="System.Id" />
                      <LinkColumn RefName="System.WorkItemType" />
                      <LinkColumn RefName="System.Title" />
                      <LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo" />
                      <LinkColumn RefName="System.State" />
                      <LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment" />
                    </LinkColumns>
                    <WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                    <WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="includeAll" />
                  </LinksControlOptions>
                </Control>
              </Tab>
              <Tab Label="Attachments">
                <Control Type="AttachmentsControl" Label="" LabelPosition="Top" />
              </Tab>
            </TabGroup>
          </Column>
        </Group>
      </Layout>
    </FORM>
  </WORKITEMTYPE>
</witd:WITD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes after you removed the `Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin` action. Now when you add a related work item, the only option available is Associate.

After inserted back this action, you still can't see the resolve. This may caused by you didn't add all of the actions back. Both in the translation and  Bug WIT. Since these are the two types of work items that you would typically associate your check-ins to.  You can do it through TFS Power Tools instead of the code directly. More detail info and steps, please refer this link: [Changing the Default CheckIn Option to Associate in TFS 2012](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/changing-default-checkin-option-associate-tfs-2012/)

[image]

To be a workaround , you can also use a new Work Item Template (WIT) which with this action.

Comment: What do y ou mean by "in the translation" ? I had a backup for the XML Bug WIT (which still has the Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin action) and even after the restore, the resolve option didn't come back. I did the backup and restore using VS 2013 (you don't need to use Power Tools anymore). Do I have to change other file besides the Bug WIT XML ?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong type. I mean the transition. Please also restore the Task WIT. And there two actions in task WIT which including New –> Closed and the Active –> Closed transitions.  And make sure all of  the above WITs have been updated into your team project  in TFS server.

Comment: Since the WITs have been updated into your team project this will be available for all users.  Did your colleagues also only can see the associate? If they can see the reslove, there must be something wrong in your local machine. Try to clear TFS and VS cache https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/. If they also can't see the reslove, there must still be something wrong with your WITS. Please double check it. Make sure you updated the right WITS in your team project.

Comment: Hi Patrick, tks a lot for your effort, but I can't find the solution yet. I did a restore for both bug and task WIT but neither do I nor my colleagues can see the resolve option. I double check both XML files (manually, exporting or in Visual Studio IDE) and everything seem to be fine. I already checked the configuration.xml (witadmin exportprocessconfig, since the exportcommonprocessconfig is deprecated) and it seems to be fine too. I really don't know where to investigate further to resolve this issue. My TFS version is 12.0.31101.0 (Tfs2013.Update4). Tks again.